# How to config vim to make the completion like Xcode?

Tags: xcode, vim

I found the code completion of Xcode is much convenient,but how to make it for vim?
Any plugins support or how config the vim file?

Comment: Use an IDE if you need IDE features.

Answer (score 1):

Vim supports some kinds of completion out of the box: `:help ins-completion`.

There are several packages that expand this system, most well-known among them being YouCompleteMe and NeoComplete/NeoComplCache.

There are specialised solutions for individual languages, such as `eclim` for Java (which connects to an Eclipse server, and thus can actually understand Java and provide many IDE features).

But ultimately, as romainl says, Vim is an editor, not an IDE, and if you're trying to use it as an IDE, expect pain.